# Assigned context gets released for new nsmanagedobject passed in segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

So I have two view controllers. View controller A segues to view controller B. In prepareForSegue in view controller A, it creates a new managed object context and assigns my global UIManagedDocument context as the parent context. I then create a new managed object using the child context and assign it to a strong property of view controller B.

As soon as viewDidLoad finishes in view controller B, the managed object is still valid (which is what I expect), but the managed object context for this new object gets set nil.

I know the variable *context below goes out of scope at the end of prepareForSegue, but I would expect for the global parent context to retain the child context, or the managed object to retain the context itself.

Here is a very slightly modified version of my code for prepareForSegue in view controller A.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerB class]]) {

        // Create new context and assign its parent
        NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [myGlobalUIManagedDocument managedObjectContext];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        context.parentContext = mainContext;

        // Create new managed object using the context
        NSManagedObject *objectB = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ObjectB" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        // Pass the object to the destination view controller
        ViewControllerB *vcB = (ViewControllerB *)vc;
        vcB.strongManagedObjectProperty = objectB;
    }
}
```

Now to my best knowledge none of the code in view controller B is setting the context to nil. I just would like to know, if from the information I have given, that the managed object context for *objectB *should* still be non-nil as soon as prepareForSegue loses scope. If so, I've some more debugging to do it seems.

UPDATE: I was able to track the exact moment my contexts gets set to nil as sometime after viewWillAppear and before viewDidAppear in view controller B. I am totally confused.

Comment: I'm no Core Data expert, but have you tried passing the context to view controller B and then creating the new NSManagedObject in view controller B instead?

Comment: how are you accessing the child context in view controller B?

Comment: @geraldWilliam - That was kind of the way I was doing it before..passing a context and an nsmanagedobjectID. I just thought passing the managedobject would be a cleaner approach. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Rakesh - I don't ever access it directly. I just assign a few outlets using the managed object in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I experience the exact thing - passed managedObject between viewControllers, and the object dropped the context between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never actually figured out what was happening here.

My solution was to create a UIManagedObjectContext property on my singleton class called editingContext that manages my UIManagedDocument. It is responsible for creating a context as a child of the UIManagedDocument's main context, and storing it in its own property.

Because of that, the context doesn't get set to nil whenever I pass it to view controller B. When I am done with the context, I just send a checkinContext: method to my singleton to release the editing context.

Kind of a hack, but I can use this method with all my segues and get the benefit of having a "scratch" context that I can throw away if the user cancels their actions.